# Why does CSS not support numbered prefixes?

Tags: css, dom, browser

I just spent a few good minutes debugging why my CSS was not taking. It turns out that naming a CSS class `2col` (vs `col2`) simply does not compile in the browser. Why is this? That is what is reserved about the numbers in CSS class prefixes?

Comment: no real reason I guess, just what the spec says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: no idea too, but you can use `[class="2col"] {...}` that works.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* begin CSS classes with numbers. You just need to escape the first one for it to work.

```css
.\32-4-1 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="2-4-1"></div>
```

Alternatively you can use the whitespace separated attribute selector `~=`:

```
[class~="2-4-1"]
```

It's also worth noting that [the HTML5 spec does not restrict the allowed characters in the `[class]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#classes).

Comment: [Here's a fiddle because snippets are currently erroring](http://jsfiddle.net/8yvrydgn/).

Comment: This is great. I had no idea!